# Border radius on Focus input field

Tags: html, css

how can we adjust the border radius of the input field focus.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="rest" />
```

CSS

```
.rest{border-radius:15px;border:1px solid red;}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `:focus` pseudo selector

```
.rest:focus{
    border-radius:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/QqLgg/)**

Comment: it's not working I want to change blue browser focus border radius

Comment: The blue border is the browser default color. What styles do you want for the border on focus?

Comment: i want border radius on that blue border :(

Comment: @CSSGuy you are looking for `outline: none`.. try `.rest:focus{outline: none}`

Comment: Add any styles to within this declaration for the focus state `.rest:focus{
    // write all the styles you need for the focus state. for eg border-radius:5px;
}`

Comment: outline:none and then add border than working fine thanks for your help

Answer (score 40):

Removed the standard outline (which does not accept border-radius) and used a blue box-shadow instead:

```css
.rest{
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.rest:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #0066ff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="rest" />
```

[**codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNxJNV)

Answer (score 6):

You have to disable the outline of the element focus state:

```
*:focus { /*OR .rest:focus*/
    outline:none;
}
```

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/JfMyj/)**

If you want the border-radius on the browser default focus outline you can do it only on firefox with `-moz-outline-border:5px;` , but this will only work on FF, however the request to implement a similar feature in WebKit was closed as WONTFIX, The plan for the future is to make the outlines follow the borders.

Comment: i want border radius on browser default blue border :(

Comment: outline:none and then add border working fine thanks for your help

Comment: I edited the answer, check it out .. you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have covered the solution, however, the supplied CSS styles do not accurately reproduce the blue ring color or size. For example, replacing:

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

With the solutions provided, results in a purple-tinted blue 
[before and after pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUcd3.png). Instead, try this color:

```
.rest:focus {
  outline: none; 
  border-radius: 8px;  /* Your border radius here */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,100,255,1),
              0px 0px 2px rgba(0,100,255,1),
              0px 0px 3px rgba(0,100,255,1); /* #0064FF */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the default outline when input is in focus and adding a border that should match the border radius of the default state of input

```
.rest:focus {
   outline: none;
   border: 1px blue solid;
}
```