# Not sure what's overriding "focus" for form fields

Tags: css

This seems to have the solution I need...

[Border radius on Focus input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081588/border-radius-on-focus-input-field)

Where I want the focus border to match the border radius used for the box itself. As it is right now, the box has curved corners but the focus does not so it looks odd.

I tried...

```
*:focus {
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px blue;
}
```

and...

```
.field-box:focus {
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px blue;
}
```

but neither work so I'm thinking something at a parent level is overriding it. When I check for the css in inspect, I don't see it show up so I can't confirm that is the case. I just know that I can make other changes to the form box but not the focus border itself. Anyone know how to address or if there is a way to identify what might be overriding it?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: That's like saying that your feet are wet and you are asking if it's raining out where you are. For all we know you could be standing in a bathtub. Please add the rest of the CSS and the relevant HTML as a [mcve]

Comment: @NullPointer - no. Also zer00ne, got it. I was hoping there was a way to see the focus element in inspect element in Chrome.  I'll see if there is a way to minimize this

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/